# Need responsive on mobile but not responsive on desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I followed these steps to make bootstrap not responsive on desktop but responsive on mobile

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

But it is also not-responsive on mobile. How can I make it responsive on mobile?

```
  <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
```

In my custom css

```
@media(max-width:480px) {
  .container {
    width: 480px !important;
  }
}

.container { width: 970px !important; }
```

HTML

```
        <div class="row topBlock" id="topBlock">
            <div class="col-xs-5 text-center">
                <div class="marketing" id="download">
                    <div class="col-xs-12" class="download-badges1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7 text-center">
            </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as *"responsive on mobile and not responsive on desktop"*. If it adapts to device width, it's responsive. If it's broken (develops a horizontal scrollbar), it's not responsive. I believe the real answer to your question lies in you telling us what you understand by *"not responsive on desktop"*. If what you mean is "full-width on desktop", replace `container` class with `container-fluid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.container { width: 970px !important; }` is overriding your media query. Reverse the selectors and set the width to `auto;` in the media query so `.container` does not have a fixed width and will expand to fill the viewport.

```
.container { width: 970px; }
@media( max-width: 480px ) {
  .container { width: auto; }
}
```

Or better yet, usa a mobile first approach and only define a width when the viewport has scaled beyond on certain width.

```
@media( min-width: 481px ) {
  .container { width: 970px; }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

@media ( min-width: 360px ) {
  div {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: gold;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

It's easy to think that wrapping a selector in a media query would give it a higher specificity, but it doesn't.

```
@media ( min-width: 360px ) {
  .abc { color: red; }
}
.abc { color: blue; }
```

Amounts to:

```
.abc { color: red; }
.abc { color: blue; }
```

Where `.abc` is going to be `blue` because the specificity of `.abc` remains the same, regardless of it being in media query. So the latter rule wins out.

Comment: This does solve a bug in my code. But my original question remains. I need responsive on mobile but unresponsive on desktop. With changes above, the width gets fixed to 480px but it does not do fluid layouts on mobile.

Comment: Then it takes 970px. How can I override 970px to no width in media query.